# How to encrypt the in-transit data movement between data source and kinesis firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-agent

I am building an architecture in which real-time data will be ingested into the kinesis firehose using kinesis agent.
My data source is on-premise so it requires that the data should be encrypted in-transit.
Which protocol is used while data is moved using agent to firehose?
Any idea on how to move data securely? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Kinesis Streams` and `Firehose` AWS endpoints **use only HTTPS** as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/fh.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ak.html). Thus by injecting your records to the Stream or Firehouse you must use `HTTPS` which provides encryption **in transit**. If this is not enough you could establish a VPN connection between on-premises and your VPC, or even use fully dedicated connection by means of direct connect.

For **server side encryption** in Firehose, you can refer to the following:

- [Data Protection in Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/encryption.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So does it mean the following:
HTTPS protocol is used while writing data into the kinesis firehose using kinesis agent?
I'm using the below endpoint in the agent.json file of the kinesis agent:

firehose.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: @Sains Yes. As shown in the links in the answer, you can only use HTTPS. No plain-text connections (i.e. HTTP) are supported. For comparison, you can check [S3 endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html) which support both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: @Sains No problem. Glad I could help.